Using MockBean to mock SessionFactory
I have a DAO impl class that I'm trying to write a unit test for using testng. My class has a SessionFactory autowired into it which is why I'm using the MockBean annotation in my test class. In my actual class that I want to test, I have the following line of code:
 Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ArchiveItem.class);

In order to run the test, I'm trying to stub the behavior of the SessionFactory. Currently, I'm not even able to create a stub on the getCurrentSession method.
This is my current test class:
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:test-context.xml")
public class MyDAOImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Mock
    private Session session;

    @Mock
    private Criteria criteria;

    @MockBean
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MyDAOImpl myDaoImpl;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoad(){
        System.out.println("Context Loads");

    }
}


However, when I run this, I get a:
java.lang.NullPointerException

This appears to be coming from the following line of code:
Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);


What line is giving you the NullPointer?

@DanieldeJong93 Its this one:
Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);

As i am not very familiar with TestNG i am not sure if this will help, but could you try and add the @SpringBootTest annotation on top of your test class?

@DanieldeJong93 Unfortunately that's throwing a "Method Not Found" error

Question details should appear in the question itself and not in comments. Can you [edit] your question and indicate which line of your code is throwing the NullPointerException? Having said that, it appears that either sessionFactory is null or sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() returns null. You need to find out which and then find out why.

Why do you mix Spring Boot annotations (@MockBean and @Autowired) with Mockito annotations (@Mock)?

Thank you everyone for your help. I found that the issue had to do with testng requiring the @Autowired annotation with @MockBean:
@MockBean injected correctly but with null value on test class
Also, I was using mockito-all and I had to upgrade to mockito-core. I'm using Java 8 and I found version 3.2.4 worked for me.
